# Responsive image gallery with CSS grid: How can I stretch one img to be bigger than it actually is?

Tags: html, css, image, grid

I'm making a responsive photo gallery using CSS grid. Everything is mostly fine until you stretch the browser width to above 1240px. One image should take up the space of four images but as the browser gets really big the image doesn't take up all the space that I want it to. I think it's because the original size of the image is 800x600. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
I'm doing the project on CodePen if you would like to see it: https://codepen.io/Zakkku/pen/JjrPPGo

````
<style>
.gallery {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 10px;
  
  
  
}




img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  object-fit: fill;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  
  .gallery {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto;
    
  }
  
  
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  
  .gallery {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
    
  }
  .noods {
    grid-area: 1 / 2 / 3 / 4;

    object-fit: fill; 
  }
}
</style>
  <body>
    <div class="gallery">
      <div class="pic">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1477925518023-22b33cbd802c?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=600&ixid=MnwxfDB8MXxyYW5kb218MHwxOTA3Mjd8MXx8fHx8fDE2MzgxNDc1MzY&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&utm_campaign=api-credit&utm_medium=referral&utm_source=unsplash_source&w=800" alt="Figs" width="800" height="600">
      </div>
      <div class="pic noods"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1462618521524-07d259ab774a?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=600&ixid=MnwxfDB8MXxyYW5kb218MHwxOTA3Mjd8MXx8fHx8fDE2MzgxNDc2NTU&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&utm_campaign=api-credit&utm_medium=referral&utm_source=unsplash_source&w=800" alt="Noodles"></div>
      <div class="pic"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/44/Y51aFguqRcGTgsYRYBXV_20140104_085932.jpg?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=600&ixid=MnwxfDB8MXxyYW5kb218MHwxOTA3Mjd8MXx8fHx8fDE2MzgxNDc3NDA&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&utm_campaign=api-credit&utm_medium=referral&utm_source=unsplash_source&w=800" alt="Razzberries"></div>
      <div class="pic"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/24/Tea-Time.png?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=600&ixid=MnwxfDB8MXxyYW5kb218MHwxOTA3Mjd8MXx8fHx8fDE2MzgxNDc4NTc&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&utm_campaign=api-credit&utm_medium=referral&utm_source=unsplash_source&w=800" alt="Green Tea"></div>
      <div class="pic"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1471193945509-9ad0617afabf?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=600&ixid=MnwxfDB8MXxyYW5kb218MHwxOTA3Mjd8fHx8fHx8MTYzODE0NzkwMg&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&utm_campaign=api-credit&utm_medium=referral&utm_source=unsplash_source&w=800" alt="Veggies"></div>
      <div class="pic"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1433155805822-ffc337821a5b?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=600&ixid=MnwxfDB8MXxyYW5kb218MHwxOTA3Mjd8fHx8fHx8MTYzODE0Nzk0Mg&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&utm_campaign=api-credit&utm_medium=referral&utm_source=unsplash_source&w=800" alt="Brilliant Buffet"></div>
      <div class="pic"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1470162656305-6f429ba817bf?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=600&ixid=MnwxfDB8MXxyYW5kb218MHwxOTA3Mjd8fHx8fHx8MTYzODE0Nzk4Mg&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&utm_campaign=api-credit&utm_medium=referral&utm_source=unsplash_source&w=800" alt="More Green Tea"></div>
      <div class="pic"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1443131307017-4097c8ac7763?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=600&ixid=MnwxfDB8MXxyYW5kb218MHwxOTA3Mjd8fHx8fHx8MTYzODE0ODI3Mg&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&utm_campaign=api-credit&utm_medium=referral&utm_source=unsplash_source&w=800" alt="lemonade"></div>
      <div class="pic"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1474152042542-1e794677a34b?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=600&ixid=MnwxfDB8MXxyYW5kb218MHwxOTA3Mjd8fHx8fHx8MTYzODE0ODM1NA&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&utm_campaign=api-credit&utm_medium=referral&utm_source=unsplash_source&w=800" alt="Grapes"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>```
````

Comment: An another approach could be to use all these images as a backgrounds, and use `background-size : cover`. That’s a little more fool-proof than what is there now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per [Sujan Sundareswaran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6014083/sujan-sundareswaran) here is a working example.

```css
    .gallery {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      gap: 10px;

    }

    img {
      max-width: 100%;
      height: auto;
      width: auto;
      object-fit: fill;
    }

    @media screen and (min-width: 768px) {

      .gallery {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: auto auto;

      }

    }

    @media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {

      .gallery {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
      }

      .noods {
        grid-area: 1 / 2 / 3 / 4;

        object-fit: fill;
        background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1462618521524-07d259ab774a?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=600&ixid=MnwxfDB8MXxyYW5kb218MHwxOTA3Mjd8MXx8fHx8fDE2MzgxNDc2NTU&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&utm_campaign=api-credit&utm_medium=referral&utm_source=unsplash_source&w=800");
        background-size: cover;
      }
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>


<head>
  <meta name="viewport"
    content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, shrink-to-fit=no" />

</head>

<body>

  <div class="gallery">
    <div class="pic">
      <img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1477925518023-22b33cbd802c?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=600&ixid=MnwxfDB8MXxyYW5kb218MHwxOTA3Mjd8MXx8fHx8fDE2MzgxNDc1MzY&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&utm_campaign=api-credit&utm_medium=referral&utm_source=unsplash_source&w=800"
        alt="Figs" width="800" height="600">
    </div>
    <div class="pic noods"></div>
    <div class="pic"><img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/44/Y51aFguqRcGTgsYRYBXV_20140104_085932.jpg?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=600&ixid=MnwxfDB8MXxyYW5kb218MHwxOTA3Mjd8MXx8fHx8fDE2MzgxNDc3NDA&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&utm_campaign=api-credit&utm_medium=referral&utm_source=unsplash_source&w=800"
        alt="Razzberries"></div>
    <div class="pic"><img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/24/Tea-Time.png?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=600&ixid=MnwxfDB8MXxyYW5kb218MHwxOTA3Mjd8MXx8fHx8fDE2MzgxNDc4NTc&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&utm_campaign=api-credit&utm_medium=referral&utm_source=unsplash_source&w=800"
        alt="Green Tea"></div>
    <div class="pic"><img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1471193945509-9ad0617afabf?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=600&ixid=MnwxfDB8MXxyYW5kb218MHwxOTA3Mjd8fHx8fHx8MTYzODE0NzkwMg&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&utm_campaign=api-credit&utm_medium=referral&utm_source=unsplash_source&w=800"
        alt="Veggies"></div>
    <div class="pic"><img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1433155805822-ffc337821a5b?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=600&ixid=MnwxfDB8MXxyYW5kb218MHwxOTA3Mjd8fHx8fHx8MTYzODE0Nzk0Mg&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&utm_campaign=api-credit&utm_medium=referral&utm_source=unsplash_source&w=800"
        alt="Brilliant Buffet"></div>
    <div class="pic"><img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1470162656305-6f429ba817bf?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=600&ixid=MnwxfDB8MXxyYW5kb218MHwxOTA3Mjd8fHx8fHx8MTYzODE0Nzk4Mg&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&utm_campaign=api-credit&utm_medium=referral&utm_source=unsplash_source&w=800"
        alt="More Green Tea"></div>
    <div class="pic"><img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1443131307017-4097c8ac7763?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=600&ixid=MnwxfDB8MXxyYW5kb218MHwxOTA3Mjd8fHx8fHx8MTYzODE0ODI3Mg&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&utm_campaign=api-credit&utm_medium=referral&utm_source=unsplash_source&w=800"
        alt="lemonade"></div>
    <div class="pic"><img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1474152042542-1e794677a34b?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=600&ixid=MnwxfDB8MXxyYW5kb218MHwxOTA3Mjd8fHx8fHx8MTYzODE0ODM1NA&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&utm_campaign=api-credit&utm_medium=referral&utm_source=unsplash_source&w=800"
        alt="Grapes"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Good solution! I didn't think of that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

it's working, only check below and work great. no need to more

```
 img {
        max-width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        width: 100%;
        object-fit: fill;
    }
```

Comment: Wow very simple! Thank you

Comment: My pleasure @Zakku